# Rudin Theorem 3.2(a)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

Rudin's theorem 3.2(a) says (for $X$ a metric space):

> $\{p_n\}$ converges to $p \in X$ if and only if every neighborhood of $p$ contains $p_n$ for all but finitely many $n$.

Rudin's definition of a neighborhood from chapter 2 of a point $p$ is:

> a set $N_r (p)$ consisting of all $q$ such that $d(p,q) < r$, for some $r > 0$.

However, another common definition I have seen is an open set containing a point. This is relevant, because of the way Rudin structures his proof. Here is the forward direction.

> Suppose $p_n \to p$ and let $V$ be a neighborhood of $p$. For some $\epsilon > 0$, the conditions $d(q,p) < \epsilon, q \in X$ imply $q \in X$. Corresponding to this $\epsilon$, there exists $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies $d(p_n, p) < \epsilon$. Thus $n \geq N$ implies $p_n \in V$.

I can't tell which definition Rudin is using here. If we were using Rudin's definition from earlier in the book, I could rewrite the above proof as follows.

> Suppose $p_n \to p$ and let $V = N_{\epsilon} (p)$. By definition, if $q \in X$ has the property that $d(q,p) < \epsilon$, then $q \in N_{\epsilon} (p) = V$. Using this same $\epsilon$, we can use the definition of sequence convergence to find $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, we have $d(p_n, p) < \epsilon$, in which case $p_n \in V$ for $n \geq N$.

Is this a proper restatement of the proof? I might be having trouble distinguishing between the properties of metric spaces and sequences, which Rudin seems to be highlighting here. I would be inclined to omit the second sentence above and, after defining $V$ in terms of $\epsilon$, simply go right to finding $N$. It concerns me a bit that my proof might be more terse than Rudin's.

Comment: Your restatement is correct given Rudin's definition of neighbourhood, which I find somewhat unusual: his neighbourhoods are what I would call discs or balls. You always have to be careful about the term neighbourhood of $x$: we've just discussed how Rudin uses it; some authors use it to mean an open set containing $x$ and some use to mean a set containing an open set containing $x$ (so they can sensibly talk about compact neighbourhoods, for example).